# Перепрыгнуть на другой Textbox

Tags: c#

Как мне сделать, чтобы при вводе в textbox перекидывала на следующий
не используя Tab (TabIndex)
К примеру через событие Textbox_textChanged.

Comment: *SetFocus* или что-то подобное есть в *C#*?

Comment: @vikttur Я через Select сделал

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Если кому интересно:

```
textBox2.Select();
```

Comment: textBox2.Focus();